# On sampling from all the continuous functions in [0,1]

Tags: self-study, sampling, simulation, stochastic-processes, measure-theory

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAYA2Mu51bw) youtube video for motivation on measure theory and at the 7:20  mark a reason for utilizing measure theory is given; to be able to pick a random function from all the continuous functions in the interval $[0,1]$ on $R$.

The creator of the video then goes on to explain that we can create a sigma algebra on the set $C([0,1], R)$ because it is a Banach space. On this sigma algebra we can then define a measure that introduces the randomness.

My question is this: is this only a theoretical result upon which we can build on or is it possible to ,say with a computer program, pick a random continuous function from $C([0,1], R)$? if it possible then how?

It should be noted that this is a soft question. I would just like to have a general understanding of how this would work.

Comment: It all depends on what you call picking a function: if you only need to define it at a finite number of points, yes we can! Take for instance a Brownian motion: it can be simulated at a finite number of points as a sequence of Gaussian variates.

Comment: To add to what @Xi'an has said, a computer program cannot pick just any random continuous function: there are too many for it to be able to represent them all. However, a program can approximate random selection by choosing from a *finite dimensional subspace* of $C([0,1])$. For instance, it could form a finite trigonometric sum or a finite wavelet expansion with random coefficients. These approaches go beyond being defined "at a finite number of points," but the same underlying abstract idea is in force: the computer must work with finite discrete approximations to mathematical objects.